# Calculation of the oscillation frequency of a rotating system that performs small oscillations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

I'm currently learning physics and sometimes I don't know how to approach a problem. I ran into this problem with oscillations combined with a circular motion, and I can't really find the answer.

Problem:

An object of mass  is placed in the configuration (on a tray) below between two identical springs.
The whole system rotates around an axis that passes through the middle of the tray with angular speed . Does this
system perform small oscillations? If it does, what are the oscillation frequency and its equilibrium position?

[image]

I started my demonstration with the following statement: **If the body is in the equilibrium position, then there will be no small oscillations.**

But since it's not specified, there comes to mind the idea of the body NOT being in the equilibrium position. I assume it will oscillate because there will be a return force proportional to the distance from the eq. position.

I thought about the case where the system is not rotating:

So the equivalent force would be: [image]and the period of oscillation:

[image]

I know that this is an answer to a whole other case, and my feeling is (because I am not sure how to prove it) that the period should depend on the rotation frequency of the tray.

What do I need to do in order to prove that? And what should the answer be in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state that:

$$\vec{F}=-2kx$$

But one side cannot be a vector and the other not. Either you choose both sides to be scalars ($F=-2kx$) or both sides to be vectors ($\vec{F}=-2k\vec{x}$)

You've also not really specified a coordinate system. I'm guessing you're looking at $m$ in a rotational frame with origin at the centre and an $x$-axis pointing horizontally outward.

You state that the period of oscillation is:

$$T=2\pi \sqrt{\frac{m}{2k}}$$

For a simple harmonic oscillator (SHO) that would be true and it is derived from the Newtonian equation of motion (NEM) of the system:

$$m\ddot{x}=-2kx$$

But your system is slightly different because there's an extra force in play: to keep on a circular track the mass $m$ has to experience a [Centripetal Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_force#Formulae) $F_c$:

$$F_c=mx\omega^2$$

So that the NEM becomes:

$$m\ddot{x}=-2kx+mx\omega^2$$

Or:

$$m\ddot{x}=(-2k+m\omega^2)x$$

Solve this ODE to find $T$.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a homework question, I will only give a strategy
how to approach this problem.

1. You have already found the force by the two springs acting on the mass $m$.
2. Now you need to find the centrifugal force acting on the mass $m$.
3. Add these forces to get the total force.
4. Then apply Newton's second law to get a differential equation.
5. Discuss this differential equation to see
   if this equation even describes an oscillation or something else.
   Hint: The answer may be different depending on the values of $m$, $k$ and $\omega$.